# Add UIButtons in UIScrollView Programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview, uibutton

I am new to iPhone development, and I want to know how can I add `UIButton`s in a `UIScrollView`?

These buttons should be vary from `12` to `20`, `24`, `28` etc.

Is there any code from that we can do this dynamically, not from Nib file, and is there any samples avaliable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can add the buttons manually with something like the following:

```
[scrollView addSubview:yourButton];
```

You can create both things via IB and set the button's frame vía code

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
[self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70,320, 70)];
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(2370, 70)];

int x = 0;
for (int i=0; i<[your array count]; i++) {

    // view allocation
    ButnView=[[UIView alloc] init];
    [ButnView setFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 82, 70)];

    // label allocation
    UILabel* butnheaderlabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(14, -10, 80, 70)];
    UILabel* butnfooterlabel  = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(27, 10, 80,70)];
    [butnheaderlabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]];

    // button allocation
    btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,82, 70)];
    [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [btn setTag:i];
    [[btn layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [[btn layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor grayColor].CGColor];
    NSString*resourceKey=[your array objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray*seperatedStr=[resourceKey componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn addSubview:butnheaderlabel];
    [btn addSubview:butnfooterlabel];
    [ButnView addSubview:btn];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:ButnView];
    x+=81;
}
```